# Show rows from another tables if exist (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I want to show data that a user can modify. If the user do changes, i like keeping the original data in my database.

When a user get data, he should view the data modified. 
(Much users can modiffied data).

For example:

**Products**  (non editable for users)

```
ID | Name   | Color
----------------------
1  | Apples | Yellow
2  | Pears  | Green
3  | Lemons | Yellow
```

**ModProducts**  (one row for modified product and user)

```
SourceID | UserID | Name          | Color
-------------------------------------------
1        | 3      | RedApples     | Red
1        | 4      | Sminth Apples | Green
```

Result for UserID 3:

```
ID | Name      | Color
-------------------------
1  | RedApples | Red
2  | Pears     | Green
3  | Lemons    | Yellow
```

I tryed with COALESCE, CASE but i can´t filter by UserID.

I Also tryed with GROUP BY, putting all data in same table, but I have not managed to give priority to the modified data

I'm going crazy..

Maybe you're designing the data model wrong?

Comment: What sql have you tried?

Comment: i am using mysql

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Problem solved in one table**

Table Products

```
ID | Ref | UserID | Name        | Color 
-------------------------------------------
1  | 1   | 0      | Apples      | Yellow
2  | 2   | 0      | Strawberrys | Red
3  | 3   | 0      | Lemons      | Yellow
4  | 1   | 2      | Apples      | Green
5  | 1   | 3      | MiniApples  | Green
```

I like this result

```
ID | Ref | UserID | Name        | Color 
-------------------------------------------
4  | 1   | 2      | Apples      | Green
2  | 2   | 0      | Strawberrys | Red
3  | 3   | 0      | Lemons      | Yellow
```

I resolv this form:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT * FROM Products  ORDER BY Ref, UserID DESC) AS Prod
WHERE UserID = 2 
   OR UserID = 0
GROUP BY Ref
```

Comment: This does not return the result you provide!

Answer (score 0):

You probably just misplaced the `UserID` filter. The filter on `UserID` has to be part of the outer join condition it can not be in the `where` clause. Try the following `select`:

```
select p.id, 
       coalesce(m.name, p.name) name,
       coalesce(m.color, p.color) color
from products p
left join modproducts m on m.id = p.id and 
                           m.userid = 3
```

Comment: my problem was that the sentence ended with "WHERE ModProducts.UserID = 3"

Comment: In reality, I have many fields. Is not there a better way to do it? For example in a single table ..

Comment: @n3rvio I think the SQL would be much more challenging if the data are in one table. I would keep it this way.